# Is there any way to run 32 bit apps in Catalina without virtual machines or a second OS?

Tags: macos, 32-bit, macos-catalina

Is there any way to run 32 bit apps in Catalina without virtual machines or a second OS?

The app that I want to run is [Wine](https://www.winehq.org).

Comment: Short answer to a short question: No.

Comment: Only if you build it yourself - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-to-get-wine-working-on-catalina

Comment: Use a 32-bit virtual machine.

Comment: There hasn't been a 32-bit macOS in a decade. Mojave will still run 32-bit, but VM was explicitly mentioned as not being an acceptable method.

Comment: True, but when Catalina came out a couple of years ago, Apple stated that it would not run 32-bit apps, so there is not much alternative.

Comment: Not going to happen.  Either roll back your OS to Mojave or roll back your hopes of running 32 bit code.  I myself would probably run a tiny XP VM.. chances are.. if your app will work with 32bit wine, it might very will run under XP.

Comment: cool! Thanks for your responses!